# Why does wrapping in `delayed` slow Dask down?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, dask

### Problem

I'd like to get the minimum value in a dataframe and apply a function to it.

I also would like to do this lazily. However, doing so appears to introduce a performance cost.

### Example

I believe this example captures this behaviour:

```py
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Sample data
df = dask.datasets.timeseries(end='2002-01-31')

# Sample function
def f(x):
    return 2*x

task = df['id'].min()
f(task.compute())  # Takes ~1.6s on my machine
dask.delayed(f)(task).compute()  #  Takes ~3.5s on my machine
```

Why is the second computation taking longer? Can this be improved somehow?

---

### Additional notes

- Looking at the dashboard, it appears that making `f` delayed makes the actual processing of the data slower. That is, the longer time is not caused by `f` becoming slow through `delayed`.
- If you `persist` the dataframe beforehand, the time for both tasks is equal.
- The effect appears also when you use `read_parquet` to read the data

#### Snakeviz

I have tried to visualize the tasks using [snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/). I am showing only what I think are the important parts:

##### Without `delayed`

[image]

##### With `delayed`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your input data, it seems to me that this may be related to [hashing of the input to `delayed` function](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#avoid-repeatedly-putting-large-inputs-into-delayed-calls). This is an additional operation on top of the actual calculation which can make it slower if you have a lot of input data.

Comment: Good idea, but I'm not convinced this is the case: I am passing a delayed task into the delayed function, so the hashing should not take any time whatsoever. The size of the underlying data should not matter. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I have added some `snakeviz` charts to hopefully help drill down to the root of the problem.